# Launching multiple custom urls in the main thread

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

I have 2 applications application1 & application2 with registered custom urls.I am unable launch the 2 applications sequentially as follows

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"abc://"]];
//where abc:// is the custom url of application1

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xyz://"]];
////where xyz:// is the custom url of application2
```

here the first application(ie custom url abc://) is successfully launched while the second application(ie the custom url xyz://) fails to launch even though the code runs through it in the debugger.
Any inputs/help is deeply appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

It seems sort of logical that you cannot launch two apps at once (only one can be actively seen anyway), but I can see why this could be useful.

My suggestion for a workaround would be that if you have control over application1 you could have application1 launch application2 if needed. Or pass control back to your original application and have it launch application2 then.

Also, you should definitely test this on an actual device. The simulator does not fully implement the launch url scheme.

Comment: i knew about the workaround u suggested, but the problem is that i am not allowed to make the custom url call from the application1 that is called from the original application.